# LED switching schematic explanation help

Tags: led, reverse-engineering, circuit-design

As an electronics engineer, I'm embarrassed to say that transistors have never been my strong suit outside of amplifiers, and I need a little help deciphering a schematic.

I have reverse engineered this somewhat, so it is a little difficult to know exactly which components are which, as well as direction of diodes and such, but this is the best I have. I don't have easy access to the PCB as it is fully encased in hard clear epoxy so I can't check voltages anywhere.

I know that if SW1 is closed the LEDs are dim, when SW2 is closed the LEDs are bright. When both switches are closed, the LEDs are bright, so it's as though it is acting as a logic gate.
All of the diodes and transistors are acting as a switching circuit, and preventing reverse voltages and such, but I'm having a bit of trouble following to explain the working principle.

If anyone has a strong electronics background, is it possible to step through to explain what i going on.

Thanks.

[image: schematic]

Comment: The Leds 1-12 and 13-24 are switched between series and parallel. In case of parallel connection the Q5 grounds 1-12 and Q2 supplies 13-24 (all supplied from sw2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit is hilariously complicated. There are

- 5 transistors (some of them PNP)
- 6 diodes
- 17 resistors

In my opinion it should be possible to either design a circuit with the same functionality with significant less elements, maybe half the number or to build a switching power supply with this number.

That aside there are some interesting clues in it.

Let's go for the simplest case first. SW2 closed.
Q4 and Q5 will be activated over Z1. This (Q5) will set the voltage at the cathodes of the left LED bank to almost 0V. Q4 will trigger a current over Q2, which will raise the voltage at the anodes of the right LED bank to almost 12 V. Q4 will also pull down the base of Q1 however this won't yield any significant effect because the collector of Q1 is at 12 V already.

When SW1 is closed, R2 is in series with all LED banks, reducing the current through them. Again Q4 and Q5 are activated, so is Q2. The LED banks are in parallel however with the additional series of R2. R1 is shorted by Q1, because Q1 gets its base current from the collector of Q4.

Unfortunately the value for Z1 is not given. Let's assume it's some value above 12V, e.g. 14V. Z1 together with Q3 will act as an overvoltage protection. As soon as the the breakdown voltage of Z1 is exceeded the current over R8 will trigger Q3. Q3 will then ground the bases of Q4 and Q5. Interestingly there's still a path for current over both banks of LEDs. The banks are in series then. This increases the circuits safe operating area to roughly the double voltage. In case SW1 is closed and the overvoltage protection is active another series resistor of 820 is inserted in series (R1) reducing the current further. This most likely makes sure, that in high voltage condition the light output doesn't exceed a maximum value associated with SW1.

Comment: The circuit is probably optimized for cost and ruggedness.

Comment: @Ariser, thanks. If I follow correctly by what Michal Podmanicky said above, the LED banks start as being in series for a very short time until the transistors are activated, after which the LED banks are switched to being in parallel.  I will need to do some additional circuit analysis to determine currents and voltages to then determine the component values.

Comment: Difficult to predict. With no capacities or inductivities added the speed and sequence of switching in this circuit is solely determined by parasitics.